# Should I migrate my site from Drupal 7 directly to Drupal 10, or via Drupal 9?

Tags: migrations, upgrading

I have been working through some upgrade issues with a site migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 10.
In my tests I have been running migrations from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. I wondered if there is any likely advantage in migrating content to Drupal 9 and then upgrading to 10, or if I should just go straight from 7 to 10 with the migration process?

Comment: There is no upgrade from D7 to D9/10. You need to create new site with D10 core and migrate your data from old site. Not all D7 modules were ported to D8/9/10. Needs deep analyzing of your old site

Comment: Hi, yes, as I mentioned I am migrating the data currently from D7 to D9. Just wondered if I may as well be doing the same process from D7 to D10. I can embark on my migration process on a D10 test site, just wondered if it was a good use of my time. I will update my question title for clarity.

Comment: Migrate directly to Drupal 10. The EOL date for Drupal 9 is 1 November 2023.

Comment: Thanks, I would be upgrading from D9 to D10 in any case, just wondering whether the migration to D9 would be technically easier than the migration to D10?

Comment: The answer to that question is no, @Lemmy, because all the really big changes to Drupal happened between D7 and D8. D9 and D10 both represent cleaner and more consistent iterations of the architectural ideas that came with D8.

Comment: Thanks @AlfredArmstrong. I have been pushing ahead with a D10 migration but unfortunately I can't install the field_collection module to D10 to enable a conversion of Field Collections to Paragraphs. So looks like there may be a case for targeting D9 for module compatibility.

Comment: @Lemmy I haven't tried that in D10 but the only thing you need is the custom migrations which I think come from the paragraphs module anyway

Comment: @Lemmy, if you have tested a migration path to D10 via D9 for the (very problematic) field collection data and it is working, use it. This doesn't change the advice for people asking the original question in general.

Comment: I will test the migration to D10 now without the Field Collection module and see where I get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, due to incompatibilities with Field Collections and Drupal 10, I was not able to migrate directly from Drupal 7 to Drupal 10. I had success however in migrating to Drupal 9 and converting Field Collections to Paragraphs in the process. I anticipate the next step of updating to Drupal 10 from Drupal 9 will be relatively straightforward by comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 9 loses all support in 11 days. It is not a safe target for any development activities at this time.